# Checking for file then creating

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to make a simple batch file to, get users input, search if it exists, if not, create file.

I was able to run tests with it hardcoded, but when I added the variable it will not run.

I also had it echo the full path (with the variable at the end) and that looks correct.

```
@echo off
set /p store="New DayCamp Number: (Example: 0050 or 3015) "
IF EXIST "X:\path\%Store%.txt" (
break>"X:\path\%Store%.txt"
) ELSE (
REM Do Nothing
)
echo "X:\path\%Store%.txt"
pause
```

Comment: Your description says you want to create the file if it does not exist.  You are creating it if it exists.  Essentially overwriting it.

Comment: So if you have not gotten around to reading the help file for the `IF ` command you need to use the `NOT` option.

Comment: @Squashman That was it... stupid mistake and had it backwards. Submit that as an answer and I will mark as solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Next code snippet should do the same:

```
@echo off
set /p store="New DayCamp Number: (Example: 0050 or 3015) "
break>>"X:\path\%Store%.txt"
```

**Explanation**: put together next statements **in bold**:

[Redirection](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) says:

- `command > filename`        Redirect command output to a file
- `command >> filename`       **APPEND into a file**

`break /?` says:

> …
>
> This is present for Compatibility with DOS systems. It has **no effect
>   under Windows**.
>
> …

However, using result of `set /p` requires some test to check: if a user just hits <kbd>Enter</kbd> (i.e. <kbd>Return</kbd>) [then the variable will be unchanged](http://ss64.com/nt/set.html) and could be an empty string. For instance, basic check

```
@echo off
set /p store="New DayCamp Number: (Example: 0050 or 3015) "
if NOT "%Store%"=="" break>>"X:\path\%Store%.txt"
```

Comment: Thanks for the awesome answer!